# Ufer grounding with multiple systems

Tags: electrical

When installing the ufer ground in a single building, with an expansion joint connected properly with bonding jumpers, and the foundation rebar is completely connected throughout the 800,000 sq ft pad. There is a ground ring, water systems will be grounded, grounding rods will also be placed throughout the building connecting 
i beams, and of course the systems individually connected to building steel also. So would only 1 ufer be needed for the 6 distribution systems that feed the building,  or would each 6 systems need its own ufer ground?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Others seem to know, but I need to ask: what's a "ufer" ground? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

### You only need 1 Grounding Electrode System no matter how many services, systems, or tenants you have in your building

All the grounding electrodes in a building are required to be bonded together to form a single *grounding electrode system* for the building, as per NEC 250.50:

> **250.50 Grounding Electrode System.** All grounding electrodes as described in 250.52(A)(1) through (A)(7) that are
>   present at each building or structure served shall be bonded
>   together to form the grounding electrode system. Where none
>   of these grounding electrodes exist, one or more of the
>   grounding electrodes specified in 250.52(A)(4) through
>   (A)(8) shall be installed and used.
>
> *Exception: Concrete-encased electrodes of existing buildings or structures
>   shall not be required to be part of the grounding electrode system where
>   the steel reinforcing bars or rods are not accessible for use without
>   disturbing the concrete.*

Furthermore, NEC 250.58 requires that all services feeding a structure use the same grounding electrode system:

> **250.58 Common Grounding Electrode.** Where an ac system is
>   connected to a grounding electrode in or at a building or structure, the same electrode shall be used to ground conductor
>   enclosures and equipment in or on that building or structure.
>   Where separate services, feeders, or branch circuits supply a
>   building and are required to be connected to a grounding electrode(s), the same grounding electrode(s) shall be used.
>
> Two or more grounding electrodes that are bonded together
>   shall be considered as a single grounding electrode system in
>   this sense.

Comment: Concur, that's what we have with our three services.

Comment: I agree with that also,  thank you. There are real electricians out there still, but a dying breed.  Now would that ufer need to be located at one of the 6 distribution points where the intersystem bonding termination point will be located, or could it be connected at any random accessible point in the building, (e.g. a random I beam).

Comment: @Jim -- 250.62 and 250.68(C) point 3 permit the latter approach (using the building steel as part of the grounding electrode conductor network, that is)

Comment: Thank you sir for learning your craft. I wish I could find a good company that actually had competent craftsmen. Mosy times the guys I work with are our biggest challenge.      Sincerely, looking for another position, anywhere usa. :-)  really...